# Get the CSRF token for the running jupyter notebook on sagemaker studio

Tags: jupyter-notebook, csrf, amazon-sagemaker-studio

how do I get the CSRF token for a jupyter notebook on Amazon sagemaker studio?

I am running the following command in the notebook named "test.ipynb" on sagemaker studio notebook instance:

```
import requests
url = https://<id>.studio.<region>.sagemaker.aws/jupyter/default/lab/tree/test.ipynb
response = requests.get(url)
```

this is giving me response [403].. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is receiving a 403 response as `requests` is not authorised.

If you want to access SageMaker Studio via URL, you’ll need to create a pre-signed link.

This is done automatically when launching Studio from the AWS Console or IAM Identity Center, however, the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) makes this easy with the `create-presigned-domain-url` command [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-presigned-domain-url.html).

Depending on your use-case, it may be easier to perform this using boto3, the AWS Python package. [Here’s](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/create_presigned_domain_url.html) the guide.